# Disabled radio buttons still clickable

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and using radio button groups

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="option1" class="control-label col-md-4">Option 1</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn">
                <input id="opt1-yes" name="option1" type="radio" value="1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input id="opt1-no" name="option1" type="radio" value="0"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="option2" class="control-label col-md-4">Option 2</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn">
                <input id="opt2-yes" name="option2" type="radio" value="1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
                <input id="opt2-no" name="option2" type="radio" value="0"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('input[type=radio][name=option2]').change(function() {      
    if($('#opt2-yes').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type="radio"][name="option1"]').attr('disabled', true).parent('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        $('#opt1-no').prop('checked', true);
        $('#opt1-yes').parent('.btn').removeClass('active');
        $('#opt1-no').parent('.btn').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('input[type="radio"][name="option1"]').attr('disabled', false).parent('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Say I set the first radio button option to 'Yes' and the second option to 'Yes', the first set should change to 'No' and be disabled. This seems to work as far as i can see but if i click on the first set, i can change the option even though they're disabled

I've created a fiddle at  https://jsfiddle.net/tux7cftm/ so you can see the problem

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your stylesheet

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Refer [CSS pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Thanks...This sorted the problem